# Text pattern match & replace

Tags: java, search, full-text-search, search-engine

Any tools to replace a particular string in huge document i.e., a kind of pattern matching against a dictionary of words and should replaced with another string if required.

Kindly let me know any open source is avaliable in java or please suggest some options to try out.

Comment: What's wrong with `aString.replaceAll(what, with)` in JAVA? You may wanna check bash _sed_ command.

Comment: If you're asking for a software recommendation, ask here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/